# Google Maps API - Auto Center and Auto Zoom

Tags: javascript, php, css, google-maps

I am having trouble fitting auto center and auto Zoom on a map created from a `CSV` file that goes into a PHP array then transferred into JavaScript--code as follows -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

include "getCsvData.php";   // this is where we put the data into a PHP array called $dataArray;
// now we exit the PHP and do the HTML including our Javascript...

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var image = {
            url: 'src/icon' + 'a.png'
            ,
        };

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            <?php
            for($i = 0, $j = count($postcodes); $i < $j - 1 ; $i++) {
            ?>
            addPostCode(<?php echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', json_encode($postcodes[$i])); ?>);
            <?php } ?>
        }
        function addPostCode(zip) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': zip}, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: image,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        name: zip
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                    // latlng.extend(marker.position);
                } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        Geocode(address);
                    }, 200);
                }

                else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:90%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have found I need to use `fitBounds` but I cannot seem to get it working either the page doesn't load or it only center on one result and then I have to zoom out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's for my setup for such case, Note that I use `window` here so I can access Google objects from any scope. You need to add each marker to `mapBounds` using `extend()` method and passing the `position`.

```js
$(function(){

    window.gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: {lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446}
        });

   var addresses = ["296 Gingerbread St", "383 Hoskins Ct", "1608 Liege Dr", "519 Mandalay Ct", "342 Pleasant Summit Dr", "1757 Quiver Point Ave", "174 Rising Mesa Ct", "26 Silica Sand St", "192 Thunder Plains Way", "277 Timber Hollow St", "367 Via Pacifico", "382 Washtenaw St"];
   
   var timeOut = 0;
   $.each(addresses, function(i, address){
      setTimeout(function(){ addMarker(address) }, timeOut);
      timeOut = timeOut+1600;
   });

});



function addMarker(address) {
            geoCoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    gMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: gMap,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                    //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
                    mapBounds.extend(marker.position);
                    //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
                    gMap.fitBounds(mapBounds);
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width:80%;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius:4px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
        window.mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        window.geoCoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        window.markers = [];
}  
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```